# Nearby Connections: Why is the payload file from the Downloads folder null?

Tags: java, android, google-nearby

I'm following the File transfer example on the [Nearby Connections Exchange page](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data) (the "more complex example" code snippet).

I can send an image and receive it on another device in the Download/Nearby folder. The image is sent successfully since if I were to change the file name to give it an appropriate extension (e.g. .jpg), I can open the image in a photo gallery app.

```java
        private void processFilePayload(long payloadId) {
            Payload filePayload = completedFilePayloads.get(payloadId);
            String filename = filePayloadFilenames.get(payloadId);
            if (filePayload != null && filename != null) {
                completedFilePayloads.remove(payloadId);
                filePayloadFilenames.remove(payloadId);

                // Retrieve received file from Downloads folder
                Payload.File payloadFile2 = filePayload.asFile();
                File payloadJavaFile = payloadFile2.asJavaFile();

                if (payloadJavaFile == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Payload java file is null in processFilePayload()");
                } else {
                    payloadJavaFile.renameTo(new File(payloadJavaFile.getParentFile(), filename));
                }
            }
        }
```

**Why is the payloadJavaFile variable null?** From looking at Payload.class, I know that the result of asJavaFile() is a nullable File and that, from the [asJavaFile() method description](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Payload.File), calling asJavaFile() in processFilePayload() from within onPayloadReceived() (as is done in the example on the API page) may lead to the File not having received all of the payload's contents yet. However, I also call processFilePayload() from within onPayloadTransferUpdate() after verifying the success of the PayloadTransferUpdate, and so shouldn't the payload have received all of its contents by this stage (and not be null when calling asJavaFile() on the payload object)?

My code is almost the same as the documentation for both sending and receiving the image and file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Payload.asJavaFile() will be null if the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not properly set up for your application. You need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the AndroidManifest.xml and you need to also request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime since it is a dangerous permission. (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

To share files using Nearby Connections, your application will need all of the following:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Required for Nearby Connections -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Optional: needed to share files -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{               
                  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                  Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                },
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

We will improve the documentation to make this requirement for sharing files more obvious.

Comment: Out of the permissions listed, I believe only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION are considered to be dangerous permissions (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous). If that is the case, then I thought that I would only need to request the dangerous permissions at runtime and have all of my permissions (normal and dangerous) listed in my manifest. How come your MainActivity code snippet includes requests for normal permissions?

Comment: You were right about requesting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at runtime. 

Also, for some reason, the images that I'm receiving are simply being renamed to "image", without a file extension. What should the files be renamed to? 

This is what my processFilePayload() looks like: https://pastebin.com/sY4F0XcQ. Renaming seems to work, but the ImageView isn't getting updated. I know this is a different issue, but is this because the file name does not include an extension, so the ImageView does not recognise it as an image? If not, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You're right that only ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are the only dangerous permissions here that need to be requested at runtime. I updated the answer to reflect this. When the payloads arrive on the device, they have an arbitrary id for their filename. The renameTo function should work as expected (with extension or not), so I am not sure why your snippet isn't working. You need to rename the file to have the same extension as it had on the sender device. Ensure you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest and requested at runtime if you are writing to external storage.

Comment: I am now requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my discoverer's activity, but I still can't get the image to be loaded into an ImageView. 

I've logged the result of renameTo, which is always true. For some reason, the filename keeps getting set to "image" (no file extension), which is not what the image was called on my advertiser's end in the Download/Nearby folder.

I don't know if this helps, but I have added a check for whether the payload (retrieved from the incomingFilePayloads map) is null in onPayloadTransferUpdate()

Comment: To clarify, when you said "you need to rename the file to have the same extension as it had on the sender device", is this something that I need to do manually (e.g. by sending the file extension as a separate bytes payload)?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the source code. From what I can see, asJavaFile() is always set (and I'm not sure why it's marked as @Nullable).

Unfortunately, for me to look into it any further, I'd need you to provide me with a sample app that reproduces the bug you're seeing.

Comment: The one exception where asJavaFile is null is for an outgoing payload that was created from a ParcelFileDescriptor.

Comment: The source code is here: https://github.com/knjk04/ad_hoc/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/adhocdisplay

AdvertiserActivity sends the image and the DiscoveryActivity receives the image (and so has processFilePayload())

Comment: Darn. I didn't see anything obviously wrong in your code. It should be working. For that matter, asJavaFile should not be null in onPayloadReceived either since all it does is point to the file name. The file names are simply the payload ID inside of the Nearby folder. Can you confirm manually that you see files appearing in that folder?

Comment: Yes, I can see the files appearing in the Nearby folder

Comment: Is there anything I can do to try to work out what the problem is? 

So far, I've used both the debugging tools and log statements to figure out that payloadJavaFile is null (by separating the two initialisation statements) and I'm also sending the image without a ParcelFileDescriptor

Comment: Do you have permissions to read external storage? If not, that could be the problem. But if you do... I'm not sure. Worst case, you can derive the file name from the payload ID, but that's icky. Unfortunately, I don't have time to do a deep dive into your code.

Comment: Yes, I have permissions to read external storage. No matter, thank you for your help! I'll try other ways to rename the file

Comment: Your suggestion worked! I would be happy to mark your answer as the accepted answer if you add that comment to your answer. I managed to get renaming working by accessing the Nearby directory via an absolute file path, finding the file with the payload ID and changing the file name to the file name that I am sending across as a bytes message.

Comment: Update: Sorry, I was wrong about having the read external storage permission (I had it in my manifest but forgot to request it at runtime). John Kaczor pointed this out, but since you mentioned it first, I think it's worth attributing the fix to you. If you add that to your answer, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: It's fine, haha. John and I work together, and John actually played around with an app in order to reproduce your bug. He has also updated our public documentation to make this more clear (to be published shortly). I think he deserves it.